# Object's total size and the object values' sum

Tags: python

I have the function which returns deep object size.

```
import sys

def get_size(obj, seen=None):
    """Recursively finds size of objects"""
    size = sys.getsizeof(obj)
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    obj_id = id(obj)
    if obj_id in seen:
        return 0
    # Important mark as seen *before* entering recursion to gracefully handle
    # self-referential objects
    seen.add(obj_id)
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        size += sum([get_size(v, seen) for v in obj.values()])
        size += sum([get_size(k, seen) for k in obj.keys()])
    elif hasattr(obj, '__dict__'):
        size += get_size(obj.__dict__, seen)
    elif hasattr(obj, '__iter__') and not isinstance(obj, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
        size += sum([get_size(i, seen) for i in obj])
    return size
```

I got it from the internet (https://goshippo.com/blog/measure-real-size-any-python-object/).
For better understanding, I decided to sum each component.

Here is what I did

```
obj1 = {'check':['true','true']}
print ("The total size of the object:", get_size(obj1), end ="\n\n")

print ("Dict value size:", sys.getsizeof({'check':['true','true']}))
print ("List value size:", sys.getsizeof(['true','true']))
print ("String value size of the key's dict:", sys.getsizeof('check'))
print ("String values size of List", sys.getsizeof('true')*2)
print ("Result:",str(sys.getsizeof({'check':['true','true']})+sys.getsizeof(['true','true'])+sys.getsizeof('check')+sys.getsizeof('true')*2))
```

Here is the result what I was done.

```
The total size of the object: 239

Dict value size: 136
List value size: 44
String value size of the key's dict: 30
String values size of List 58
Result: 268
```

Why does the object's total size less than the object values' sum: 239 and 268?

I'm a beginner in Python. Please give examples.

Answer (score 1):

You're counting `'true'` twice, but due to several optimizations (interning and `co_consts` constant merging would both do it), Python ends up reusing the same string object for both `'true'` values in the list. This saves 29 bytes compared to what you calculated.

Whether two equal strings happen to be represented by the same string object is an implementation detail. You should never rely on it being one way or the other, as the details are weird and subject to change without notice.

Comment: Thanks! I have other questions:
1. In what cases it happens (only when I make list, dict or else)? `a = "a" and b = "a"` `"a"` - will it be the same object in code?
2. And with which variables types does it happen (only string or else)?
3. Can I get a link to site Python to read more about?